# How to use relationship in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, relationship

I use work with relationship in laravel 5.6.

I create `product` table with migration:

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->string('tags');
        $table->string('original_price');
        $table->integer('view_order')->default(0);
        $table->unsignedInteger('admin_id');
        $table->foreign('admin_id')->references('id')->on('admins');
        $table->boolean('status');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

And i create `category` table with migration:

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->boolean('status');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

And create `product_categories` table with migration:

```
Schema::create('product_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('product_id');
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
        $table->unsignedInteger('category_id');
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**Now, I use `Bootstrap Multiselect` for categories in one product.**

In `category` model:

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}
```

In `Product` model:

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}
```

How to add `category_id` and  `product_id` in `product_categories` table with relationship?

Comment: please do make sure that you've done enough research before asking questions here in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model names are `Product` and `Category` and the derived relational table will be `category_product` because category came before product in alphabetical order.

You only have to add the pivot table:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_categories')
}

public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'product_categories')
}
```

Now for save with relationship:

```
$product->categories()->attach($category);
$product->categories()->attach([$category_id_1, $category_id_2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the documantation related to [Many to many Relationships.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)

Your pivot table doesn't follow Laravel's convention, either update your table name or update your relationships to address this issue.

The convention is the alphabetical order of the two models, thus your pivot table should be named: `category_product`

If you do not want to update the table name, update your relationships.

```php
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_categories')
}

public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'product_categories')
}
```

Now to *"save an entry to the pivot table"* -or in other words: to create the relationship between the two models- you may use `attach` or `sync` method.

```php
$product->categories()->attach($category);
$product->categories()->attach([$categoryId1, $categoryId2]);
```

`sync` is different.

> The sync method accepts an array of IDs to place on the intermediate table. Any IDs that are not in the given array will be removed from the intermediate table.

To detach (delete entry in pivot table), simple use the `detach` method.

```php
$product->categories()->detach([1, 2]);
```

Of course, do the same for `Category`.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to add the pivot table:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_categories');
}

public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'product_categories');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, laravel derives the table name from the alphabetical order of the related model names. Here your model names are `Product` and `Category` and the derived relational table will be `category_product` because category came before product in alphabetical order. Either you can change the table name or you can override this my mentioning the table name as the second parameter in the relational method as follows.
public function products()

```
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_categories');
}

public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'product_categories');
}
```